# How to create the android project with mention version in cordova?

Tags: cordova

I am new to cordova and I have created the android project using cordova.

```
cordova create FAS com.FAS.solitaire "FAS Freecell Solitaire"
cordova platform add android@4.0.0
```

But when I published this app in Play Store, there showing ("**Requires Android
2.3.3 and up**"). But this app run only from  android version 4.2.2

This app Play Store Link is
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.FASgame.FASsolitaire

Comment: What version of Cordova are you using?

Comment: @lifeisfoo Latest version cordova 3.5.1

Comment: latests cordova CLI version is 5.2.0, and cordova android is 4.1.1, not 3.5.1. cordova android 4.1.1 supports android 4.0 (SDK 14) and up, your question is confusing

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two lines in your config.xml file

```
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />
```